# SharePoint 2010 - Attributes are not sticking

Tags: web-part

I am developing a Visual Web Part.  I have attributes the Visual Web Part consumes.  When i use these, I have to re-set the value everytime I re-deploy the web part (by hitting F5).

Here is an example:

```
    public static bool ShowCaseType= true;
    [FriendlyNameAttribute("Show Case Time When Multiple (Recomended)"),
    Category("My Configuration"),
    DefaultValue(true),
    WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared),
    Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
    WebBrowsable(true)]
    public bool _ShowCaseType
    {
        get
        {
            return ShowCaseType;
        }
        set
        {
            ShowCaseType= value;
        }
    }
```

If i set the above to unchecked in the web part, I stop the application and start it once again, and it has been reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you should change declaration of first line to following. There is no reason to keep it public static

```
private bool ShowCaseType= true;
```

Comment: I thought this had something to do with it, but then how do i get the value from this if it is not static? I need my visualwebpart (control) to be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped...   i figured out my last question: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/152e83fc-ea1b-4073-bd00-aed525f3e107

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Ashish. this is why it needs to be changed every time. Making the variable static makes it bound to the type, not the instance. So it's set 1 time, but on redeploy / iisreset will revert to it's original value. By reloading the appdomain (resetting IIS) it looses it's (in memory) value.

Comment: I thought this had something to do with it, but then how do i get the value from this if it is not static?  I need my visualwebpart (control) to be able to access it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped...   i figured out my last question: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/152e83fc-ea1b-4073-bd00-aed525f3e107